# Allocation memory for Path variable throws runtime exception

Tags: android, canvas, path

On allocating memory for a Path variable i ran into the following runtime exception:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub!
>
> at android.graphics.Path.`<init>`(Path.java:24)
>     at com.tg.MindGames.set.settings.CardStyle.getCard(CardStyle.java:17)
>     at com.tg.MindGames.set.Test.main(Test.java:16)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Native Method)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>     at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

My Code is:

```
import android.graphics.Path;
public class CardStyle {
   public static void getCard(String shapeName, int amount){
      Path p = new Path();
   }
}
```

What went wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out the Problem:

I ran a public static void main to test certain features so I didnt compile an Android app but a standard java application.
When I compile it as an Android app testing the feature in my main activity it works.